# Android Studio When I press debug it runs tests instead of Compiling Projects

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason whenever I press the debug button in android studio it runs tests from one of my libraries instead of compiling the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `Run/Debug configuration` in **Android Studio** like

[image]